# Pass Parameter to the function called in set_error_handler PHP

Tags: php, business-logic

```
function errHandle($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, $xmlArray) {
    $msg = "$errStr in $errFile on line $errLine";

    if ($errNo == E_NOTICE || $errNo == E_WARNING) {
        throw new ErrorException($msg, $errNo);
    } else {
        echo $msg;
        echo '<pre>';
    print_r($xmlArray);
    }
}

foreach($returnValues as $xmlArray){

....
....
set_error_handler(array($xmlArray, 'errHandle'));

}
```

Can i pass the array as parameter to errHandle function.

it is showing the Error: 
set_error_handler() expects the argument (SimpleXMLElement::errHandle) to be a valid callback in ...

Whole intention is to check, if there is a error in the iteration, then display that array to see the array contents in the function errHandle

Comment: Your intention is clear, however please see for that `set_error_handler` is for: http://php.net/set_error_handler - you first register the error handling function and then you execute your code you assume having an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do that directly, since there are strict rules for user-defined handler of errors.
If you are defining error handler, you can rely on context from it - that context will be passed as the last parameter and will contain current scope (i.e. scope, from which error was triggered). Here's an example:

```
function errHandle($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, $errContext) {
    $msg = "$errStr in $errFile on line $errLine";

    if ($errNo == E_NOTICE || $errNo == E_WARNING) {
        throw new ErrorException($msg, $errNo);
    } else {
        echo $msg;
        echo '<pre>';
    print_r($errContext);
    }
}

$xmlArray=['foo'=>'bar'];
set_error_handler('errHandle');

trigger_error('test', E_USER_WARNING);
```

you will be able to access `$xmlArray` from your parameter `$errContext` via corresponding key (i.e. `'xmlArray'`). For more information see [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'customErrorHandler'));
```